# Getting axis of rotation in osgSim::DOFTransform?

Tags: c++, openscenegraph

I'm working on a OSG model which contains several DOFTransform nodes. In order to perform geometric calculations on the 3D model I need to know which are the axis of rotation and the point where this axis is placed, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

osgSim::DOFTransform
http://trac.openscenegraph.org/documentation/OpenSceneGraphReferenceDocs/a00215.html

has

```
const osg::Vec3& osgSim::DOFTransform::getCurrentHPR() const;
```

to get the Euler angles for **H**eading, **P**itch and **R**oll,and

```
MultOrder osgSim::DOFTransform::getHPRMultOrder() const;
```

to get the convention intended to be used for the sequence of rotations.

The reference point can be determined by

```
const osg::Vec3& osgSim::DOFTransform::getCurrentTranslate () const;
```

---

Given a vector **v** expressed in coordinates of the frame which the translation **t** refers to, it's

**v'** = **v** - **t**

on which the rotations are to be applied.

---

For conversion of an Euler angle to an axis/angle representation pls. attend:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Conversion_formulae_between_formalisms

In addition:

Let **M** be the combined rotation matrix, e.g.

**M** = **H** * **P** * **R**

(H,P,R here denoting the respective *Matrices* for the given angles) and vectors **v'**, **v''** with

**v''** = **M** * **v'**

which are not collinear, the axis searched for is simply their normalized cross product, and the angle can be found by applying basic trigonometry.